# How to select a particular next button in form wizard

Tags: jquery, selector

I have been using a form wizard from the following link
http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples

I would like to do something in JavaScript when the user click the second next button.

I used tried the following code

```
$('a[href="#next"]:nth-child(2)').click(function() {
    alert( "Second next button was called." );
});
```

But for some reason, the function triggers in every steps. I want only that particular next button to trigger the function.
How do I do it??

Comment: can you create a minimum demo for the OP?

Comment: Which specific example on that page? Which specific element? Can you include the HTML and tell us so we can assist?

Answer (score -1):

:nth-child means nth-child element of parent elem, not only jquery-selected a tags.
Try this.

```js
$('a[href="#next"]:eq(1)').click(function() {
    alert( "Second next button was called." );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#next">first</a>
<a href="#next">second</a>
<a href="#next">third</a>
```